# Check greater than of updated_at in where clause in ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I get `updated_at` in params as a string. I convert it by using `to_time`

```
updated_at = params["latest_updated_at"].to_time
chat_history = ChatHistory.where('updated_at > ?',updated_at)
```

But it doesn't work properly. It also get a few `< updated_at` records. I want only `> update_at`.

Value of param is like `"2016-03-17 18:06:36"`

Comment: Sorry, I'm not sure what you're asking. You're saying it doesn't get "lowest lesser than updated_at". Do you mean you want the earliest `ChatHistory` record after the `updated_at` parameter? Or something else?

Comment: I update my quewstion

Comment: What is the input? Which wrong records do you get (post some)?

Comment: try this way `chat_history = ChatHistory.where('updated_at > ?',updated_at.to_date.end_of_day)` instead of using `to_time` use `to_date`

Comment: Note: Post variables and input values, when you ask any question on stackoverflow.
examples of what is intended, and what are you getting is welcome too.

Comment: @VishalJAIN that would work if `latest_updated_at` is just a date, not a specific time. Also, why convert it `to_date` if you also want `end_of_day`?

Comment: @HaseebAhmad what is the value of `params["latest_updated_at"]`? Without knowing that, it's impossible to help.

Comment: vale of param is "2016-03-17 18:06:36"

Comment: Updated it........

Comment: `"2016-03-17 18:06:36".to_time` gives you UTC time which probably is the issue.  Have you tried converting it to your configured timezone: `"2016-03-17 18:06:36".to_time.in_time_zone`?

Comment: What is your database? Postgres? MySQL? Something else?

Comment: @MilanIliev actually i am considering it as only `date` so i have used it `end_of_day` params it self has with time then no need to used it.

Comment: @HaseebAhmad, are you getting **one** or **a few** extra records, or all the records? If it's one or several, then Paul's answer below is probably right.

Comment: @MilanIliev one or few extra records

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So this might be a timezone issue. If your timestamps are always expressed in the same timezone, you can say this:

```
ActiveSupport::TimeZone['America/Los_Angeles'].parse "2016-03-17 18:06:36"
```

That will give you a `TimeWithZone` instance, which you can pass to the `where` call. (Of course change `America/Los_Angeles` to whatever is appropriate.) A shortcut might be `Time.zone.parse` if you've configured Rails to use the timezone you want.

If the timezone can vary based on, say, `current_user`, just use the user's preferences to get the right timezone, then use that to parse your string.

Btw you are getting a lot of bad advice in the comments on your question:

- You should not use `to_date`, because then you lose all sub-day resolution. If you don't account for timezones properly you might not even pick the right day!
- Parsing the string then calling `in_time_zone` does nothing, because by parsing the string you've already interpreted it in one timezone or another. `in_time_zone` doesn't change what *instant* the time is, only where you're standing at that moment, and hence whether it should be written as "5pm Pacific" or "6pm Central".

Here is some general advice on timezones in Rails, and how to reason about them (by me): http://illuminatedcomputing.com/posts/2014/04/timezones/